# Заблокированные Packages в Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой. Временами когда я гружу проекты с war файла в Eclipse, Packages не открываются в "Название проекта/Java Resources/src"
С чем это может быть связано? Т.е. когда в Packages можно зайти и просмотреть файлы он темно коричневого цвета, а которые не открываются белые.

Файлы из Packages находятся в автоматически созданной папки ImportedClasses. Можно ли их вернуть обратно в  "Название проекта/Java Resources/src"

Comment: эклипс еще жива?

Comment: Конечно. На ней идут работы.

Comment: Ностальгия по старой ide?